# mvn spring-boot:run will not execute schema.sql in resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I am trying to build spring-boot application, repo here https://github.com/tacocloud/taco-cloud, but when the maven compiles a launch it, there is no execution of the schema.sql and data.sql.

Even with this `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.sql.init.mode=always`
```

What could I do?

Comment: I think that `schema.sql` is for spring data JPA and spring data jdbc only is not sufficient.

Comment: Looks like a typo in `application.properties` where there’s a trailing back-tick in the value of `spring.sql.init.mode`

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are correct.
Take a look at the
[how-to guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization).
Add the JPA starter to your pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and a database:

```xml
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
          <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Configure the datasource in your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username: sa
spring.datasource.password:
```

You'll also likely need:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

See the discussion in the Spring how-to (linked above).